# Rails - re-using partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Instead of the standard show, edit, delete, I have the following in my views/users/index.html.erb

```
    <td>
      <%= link_to user, class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to edit_user_path(user), class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
      <% end %>
    </td>
```

How can I re-use this code for all other models in the app?

Comment: Use [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) with `3.4.4 Passing Local Variables`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `layouts/_toolbox.html.rb` partial and place the following modified version in it:

```
<td>
    <%= link_to my_model, class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">See me</span>
    <% end %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= link_to [:edit, my_model], class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">Edit me</span>
    <% end %>
</td>
<td>
    <%= link_to my_model, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Destroy me</span>
    <% end %>
</td>
```

And then you can use it with:

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/toolbox", locals: {my_model: model_instance} %>
```

Comment: It is giving me an error message: undefined local variable or method `my_model', when I used it like this: <%= render partial: "layouts/show_edit_del_buttons", locals: {user: u} %>

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper replace `{user: u}` with `{my_model: u}`.

Comment: `<%= render "layouts/toolbox", my_model: model_instance %>` is enough, can leave out 'partial' and 'locals'

Comment: removing one or more will generate an error message: undefined local variable or method `my_model'

Comment: That's strange, doesn't happen for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can move it to a partial layout and pass the variables as locals.
Notice that the partial name must begin with "_", for example: _actions.html.erb

Then render the partial from the code and pass the locals.

```
<%= render partial: "actions", locals: {user: @user} %>
```